# Airflow extra Packages failed to install due to mysqlclient

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow

I have instaled basic version of Airflow which uses Sqlite as metastore. Now i am trying to install other Packages.

I tried the below Packages but failed with mysqlclient issue.

```
pip install apache-airflow[devel]
```

**Error message with compile statement as below,**

> gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
>   -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,14,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.14 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/opt/python-2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
>   -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX

_mysql.c:29:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory

_mysql.c:30:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory

_mysql.c:48:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory

_mysql.c:67: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’

**Final Failure Command in log:**

> Command "/home/usr/Airflow_Workspace/install/bin/python -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-yeFo2f/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-Bw_HED/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/usr/Airflow_Workspace/install/include/site/python2.7/mysqlclient"
>   failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-yeFo2f/mysqlclient/

I tried installing many dependency for python but still not resolved. Could someone help me what exactly I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu/Debian, you need the `libmysqlclient-dev` system package first.

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: we have RHE 6 and i have used virtualenv to install airflow.i tried pip install libmysqlclient-dev but it could find the package.

Comment: For RHEL, the package is `mysql-devel`.

Comment: I tried pip install mysql-devel. It says No matching distribution found for mysql-devel.

Comment: These are operating system packages, not Python packages. `sudo yum install mysql-devel` for RHEL. Once you have the `mysql-devel` package installed, you can try `pip install apache-airflow[devel]` again.

Comment: Thanks yum install mysql-devel fixed. Could you update the answer so I accept.